# Arduino Nano-combo NRF2401

Tags: arduino-nano, nrf24l01+

I am using two nano-combo for a RC car and when the remote emitter battery is too down if the car was running and battery finally empty the car was still running...is there any way by programming to check communication between the two nanos and solve this problem??. Thanks.

here is the code:
//Receiver program

#include <SPI.h>;
#include "Mirf.h"
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "MirfHardwareSpiDriver.h"
Nrf24l Mirf = Nrf24l(10, 9);

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
Mirf.spi = &MirfHardwareSpi;
Mirf.init();
Mirf.setRADDR((byte *)"FGHIJ"); //Set your own address (receiver address) using
5 characters
Mirf.payload = sizeof(datos);
Mirf.channel = 90;             //Set the used channel
Mirf.config();
//Serial.println("Listening...");  //Start listening to received data

void loop()
{
if (Mirf.dataReady()) { //When the program is received, the received data is
output from the serial port
Mirf.getData(datos);
delay(5);

if (datos[7] >= 150) {     //motor forward

```
analogWrite(3,0);
analogWrite(5,255);
```

}

if (datos[7] <= 90) {    motor back

```
analogWrite(3,255);
analogWrite(5,0);
```

}

if (datos[7] > 90 && datos[7] < 150 or datos[7] == 0) { //motor stop

```
analogWrite(5,0);
analogWrite(3,0);
```

}
}
}

it works perfect I can control dc motor no problem but if remoto control battery is low or empty then no communication with NANO receiver and the motor spin itself non stop.

I try different things in the void loop like:

if (!Mirf.dataReady()) {
analogWrite(5,0);
analogWrite(3,0);  }

but still the same problem. So that´s why must be something inside Rf library to check if remote control NANO comms is off I don`t know...

Thanks

Comment: Surely. You can program your Arduino to stop, if no data was received for a specific amount of time. Though we cannot really give you more advice without more information from you. Please include your code into the question (and format it correctly as code). Also please give us more information, how everything is connected.

Comment: use a heartbeat signal

Answer (score 0):

You can do somthing like:

```
while(radio.hasData()){
}
```

This works in the NRFLite library. I don't know about other libraries like RF24 etc.